# Solving equations with square root, sin, and cos

Tags: python, numpy, math, equation

I am working on a project that involves equations with four different unknowns combined with square root, sin, and cos.

e.g.

```
 sqrt(2)+(3/2)*sqrt(3) = a*cos(b)+ c*cos(d)
-sqrt(2)+(3/2)         = a*sin(b)+ c*sin(d)
 13                    = a**2    + c**2
  5                    = a       + c
```

Possible answers (found by using GeoGebra):

```
[[a = 2, b = -45   , c = 3, d =  30   ], 
 [a = 2, b =  47.45, c = 3, d = -27.55], 
 [a = 3, b =  30   , c = 2, d = -45   ], 
 [a = 3, b = -27.55, c = 2, d =  47.45]]
```

**NB:** the variables *b* and *d* are angles in degrees (not radians)

I saw this post, [Solving linear equation with four variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58671682/solving-linear-equation-with-four-variables), where they solved it with NumPy, but that was with easier equations:

```
 a + 3b + 2c + 2d = 1
2a +  b +  c + 2d = 0
3a +  b + 2c +  d = 1
2a +       c + 3d = 0
```

where the code was:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,3,2,2],[2,1,1,2],[3,1,2,1],[2,0,1,3]])
B = np.array([1,0,1,0])
print(np.linalg.solve(A,B))
```

Output:

```
[-0.27272727 -0.18181818  1.09090909 -0.18181818]
```

I tried to use the same method, but I didn't seem to be able to convert my equations to a way this method could read.

Comment: your equations are non-linear so cannot apply a linear solver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sympy to solve the equations symbolically:

```py
from sympy import S, Eq, sqrt, sin, cos, solve
from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d

equations = [Eq(sqrt(2) + (3 / S(2)) * sqrt(3), a * cos(b) + c * cos(d)),
             Eq(-sqrt(2) + (3 / S(2)), a * sin(b) + c * sin(d)),
             Eq(13, a ** 2 + c ** 2),
             Eq(5, a + c)]
sol = solve(equations, [a, b, c, d])
```

Result:

```
[(2,
  -asin(-3/4 + sqrt(2)/2 + 3*sin(2*atan((-2*sqrt(2) + 3 + 2*sqrt(sqrt(3) + 2))/(sqrt(2) + sqrt(6) + 3*sqrt(3) + 6)))/2),
  3,
  2*atan((-2*sqrt(2) + 3 + 2*sqrt(sqrt(3) + 2))/(sqrt(2) + sqrt(6) + 3*sqrt(3) + 6))),

 (2,
  asin(-sqrt(2)/2 + 3*sin(2*atan((-3 + 2*sqrt(2) + 2*sqrt(sqrt(3) + 2))/(sqrt(2) + sqrt(6) + 3*sqrt(3) + 6)))/2 + 3/4),
  3,
  -2*atan((-3 + 2*sqrt(2) + 2*sqrt(sqrt(3) + 2))/(sqrt(2) + sqrt(6) + 3*sqrt(3) + 6)))]
```

From here, `evalf()` obtains numerical solutions (in radians):

```py
for sol_i in sol:
    print([x.evalf() for x in sol_i])
```

```
[2.00000000000000, -0.785398163397448, 3.00000000000000, 0.523598775598299]
[2.00000000000000, 0.828153484576581, 3.00000000000000, -0.480843454419166]
```